# while function not returning count correctly

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am trying to use the while function to count one of my pointers is greater than 0.

What I need is to count the amount that returned me value above 0.

Below the code of the part I use while:

```
struct mode {
    int m_mode_max[10];
    ...
}

struct gained_var {
    struct mode var1[10];
    ...
}

struct fs_session {
    struct gained_var gained[5];
    ...
}

void frist_gained(struct fs_session *fs, int value) {

    struct itv_expanse itv[5];
    memset(itv, 0, sizeof(itv));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
            while (fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0) {
                count++;
                printf("count %d\n", count);
            }
        }
    }

    itv[value].var1[i].m_mode = fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[rand()%count];
    printf("m_mode %d rnd_value %d\n", itv[value].var1[i].m_mode, rnd()%count);
}
```

I could use an if function to check count, but I want to use While

What is the best way to do this using while function?

Comment: Neither `if` nor `while` is a function, and similarly for other keywords, including `switch`, `for`, `return` and even`sizeof`.

Comment: If there are multiple instances where `fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0` does that count once or multiple times?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `while` here? An `if` inside a `for` is appropriate.

Comment: just to learn to use all possibilities. so I said at the end that I could use the if condition I wanted to know more about while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value of the condition inside the while

```
while (<SOMETHING> > 0) {
    // change the value of <SOMETHING>, otherwise
    // you get an infinite loop
}
```

In your case, maybe something like

```
        while (fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0) {
            count++;                     // does not change fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p]
            printf("count %d\n", count); // does not change fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p]
            p++;                         // <== change fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p]
        }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to check while p <= 10 to avoid problems? example `while (p <= 10 && fs>gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0)`

Comment: Yes, @Sombra, that is a very good idea in this specific instance :) though it should be `while (p < 10 && ...)`

Comment: Isn't this redundant with the `for` loop that's already iterating over `p`? Should they be combined?

Comment: `for` must be removed because inside while has `p++`

Comment: @pmg Does `while (p < 10 && fs->gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0)` work? The loop will exit as soon as `fs->gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] <= 0`.

Comment: @Schwern: I meant those `...` as the code posted by Sombra (it's kinda hard doing copy/paste on mobile phone)

Comment: @pmg I understand. Maybe there's a misunderstanding about what's being counted. Consider the simplified `int foo[] = {0, 0, 23, 42};` and `while(i < 4 && foo[i] > 0) { count++; i++ }`. The loop will exit on the first iteration and `count` will never be incremented. `int foo[] = {99, 0, 0, 23, 42};` will have a count of 1, should be 3. `int foo[] = {99, 98, 0, 0, 23, 42};` will count 2 not 4.

Comment: Ah! I was just trying to prevent access beyond array boundary; didn't even think about other situations.

Answer (score 1):

You're already looping over `i` and `p` to iterate through the structure. You need an `if` to decide to increment the counter.

The problem is you're printing the count every time its incremented. Perhaps you should only print it when the loop is complete?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
        // Typo fix: fs>gained to fs->gained
        if (fs->gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("i: %d, count: %d\n", i, count);
}
```

If the intent is to count an m_mode_max only once, you can add a `break` to exit the `p` loop once its been counted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
        // Typo fix: fs>gained to fs->gained
        if (fs->gained[value].var1[i].m_mode_max[p] > 0) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("i: %d, count: %d\n", i, count);
}
```